# Sublime Text 2: Automatically escape quotes

Tags: php, html, escaping

Using Sumblime Text 2, is there a way to automatically escape a block of HTML to use in a string or to php echo?

When wrapping lots of HTML in double quotes you have to escape all double quotes, can this be done with a command of keybind?

Simple example:

```
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id="file"><br />
```

Would become:

```
    <label for=\"file\">Filename:</label>
    <input type=\"file\" name=\"uploadedfile\" id=\"file\"><br />
```

So you can just use it like this:

```
    $output = "<label for=\"file\">Filename:</label>
    <input type=\"file\" name=\"uploadedfile\" id=\"file\"><br />"
```

Ofcourse I could just use find and replace, but since this is a common task, can it be done with a keybind that only does this to a selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not make use of single quote?

```
<?php     $output = '<label for="file">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id="file" value="'.$filename.'"><br />';

    echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: I didn't show it in this example, but I often put $variables inside double quotes, especially in HTML.

Comment: i have modified above code to to include php variable  in php variable value. hope that solves your problem

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question being asked (a requirement for sublime text keybind to escape quotes in a selection) but it provides an alternative. It would be nice to see someone answering the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the replace tool to turn this:

```
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="uploadedfile" id="file"><br />
```

Into this:

```
<label for='file'>Filename:</label>
<input type='file' name='uploadedfile' id='file'><br />
```

And then do this:

```
$output = "<label for='file'>Filename:</label>
<input type='file' name='uploadedfile' id='file'><br />";
```

HTML accepts both ' and ".

Comment: NOTE: f you're attempting to respect newlines and carriage returns in your output (E.g., for formatting in output used in email) then single quotes and double quotes in PHP handle this differently.